# Buscar em tabelas diferentes sabendo de qual veio o resultado

Tags: php, mysql

Estou tentando buscar um termo em 4 tabelas diferentes no MySQL, usando `like`, mas preciso resgatar o `id` de cada uma e identificar de qual tabela veio para fazer a listagem e direcionar com link.

Trata-se de um sistema de busca onde os resultados devem ter um link para a página correspondente com o `id` de cada resultado.

Já tentei usar 4 `selects` e `union`, mas não obtive sucesso.

Última tentativa realizada:

```
("SELECT * FROM web_tv WHERE (titulo LIKE '%".$busca."%' OR (texto '%".$busca."%')) UNION SELECT * FROM agenda WHERE (titulo LIKE '%".$busca."%' OR (texto '%".$busca."%')) UNION SELECT * FROM blog WHERE (titulo LIKE '%".$busca."%' OR (texto '%".$busca."%')) UNION SELECT * FROM osorio WHERE (titulo LIKE '%".$busca."%' OR (texto '%".$busca."%'")
```

Comment: posta o seu sql pra tentarmos te ajudar

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta adicionando o código da consulta.

Comment: Pra usar o `union`, a quantidade de colunas e os nomes delas tem que ser exatamente iguais, o que se for o caso, não faria sentido ter os registros em tabelas diferentes, você já tentou fazer as 4 consultas separadas trazendo tudo em `array` e juntando depois?

Comment: Elas não têm tabelas iguais.
A única coisa que se repete são ID, TITULO e TEXTO. O resto é diferente em cada uma.

Vou tentar fazer juntando os resultados, mas pensei que houvesse uma forma de executar a consulta diretamente no mysql.

Comment: @KennyRafael e Vitor, os nomes não precisam ser iguais em todas, apenas a quantidade e os tipos das que forem efetivamente usadas no select. Pode misturar nomes, mas para usar fora do UNION precisará usar sintaxe posicional (números indicando a coluna, em vez dos nomes)

Comment: Em outras palavras, `SELECT nome, cpf FROM pessoa UNION SELECT razao_social, cnpj FROM empresa` funciona se `nome` e `razao_social` forem do mesmo tipo, e `cpf` e `cnpj` também..

Comment: Obrigado @Bacco

Comment: Obrigado @Bacco e Kenny Rafael.
Troquei o * pelos campos que precisava realmente (id, titulo e texto) e arrumei o OR que também não estava funcionando.
Quase todos os problemas foram solucionados, porém ainda não consegui saber de qual tabela é cada linha trazida...

De qualquer forma, obrigado.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Uso geral do UNION com condição:

```
SELECT campo1, campo2 FROM tabela1 WHERE ...
UNION
SELECT campo1, campo2 FROM tabela2 WHERE ...
UNION
SELECT campo1, campo2 FROM tabela3 WHERE ...
UNION
SELECT campo1, campo2 FROM tabela4 WHERE ...
```

Ou:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT campo1, campo2 FROM tabela1 
    UNION
    SELECT campo1, campo2 FROM tabela2 
    UNION
    SELECT campo1, campo2 FROM tabela3 
    UNION
    SELECT campo1, campo2 FROM tabela4 
) todos
WHERE condicao
```

### Aplicando ao seu caso e diferenciando as tabelas:

Usualmente em SQL você não precisa retornar apenas campos, pode usar expressões envolvendo mais de um campo, ou simplesmente nem usar campos em qualquer uma das colunas. E é o que vamos fazer aqui:

```
SELECT 'web_tv' AS tabela, campo1, campo2 
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Este select retornará sempre um campo de nome `tabela` com o conteúdo `webtv`, para saber de onde veio a informação, ficando assim:

```
SELECT 'web_tv' AS tabela, campo1, campo2 FROM web_tv WHERE ...condicoes...
UNION
SELECT 'agenda' AS tabela, campo1, campo2 FROM agenda WHERE ...condicoes...
UNION
SELECT 'blog'   AS tabela, campo1, campo2 FROM blog   WHERE ...condicoes...
UNION
SELECT 'osorio' AS tabela, campo1, campo2 FROM osorio WHERE ...condicoes...
```

Recomendo usar somente os campos necessários de fato para a busca, no lugar do `*`, sempre que possível. Em algumas situações o `*` é mais prático, mas geralmente especificar as colunas é quase sempre mais seguro.

Se quiser realmente usar o `*`, pode fazer isto:

```
SELECT 'web_tv' AS tabela, * FROM web_tv WHERE ...condicoes...
UNION
SELECT 'agenda' AS tabela, * FROM agenda WHERE ...condicoes...
...
```

Mas só vai dar dor de cabeça quando você reestruturar qualquer uma delas, além de provavelmente estar retornando dados que não vai usar.

O importante é entender que criamos uma coluna literal, com os nomes da tabela original para que você saiba qual resultado veio de onde.

Se quiser simplificar, pode usar um valor numérico:

```
SELECT 1 AS tabela, * FROM web_tv WHERE ...condicoes...
```

### Dica de simplificação

Isto aqui:

```
WHERE titulo LIKE '%".$busca."%' OR texto LIKE '%".$busca."%'
```

Pode ser simplificado desta maneira:

```
WHERE concat_ws( ' ', titulo, texto ) LIKE '%".$busca."%'
```

No caso de dois campos não muda muito, mas se tiver mais campos, pode facilitar sua vida.

### Sintaxe alternativa

Antes de mais nada, importante dizer que quando você usa desta forma, provavelmente o `UNION` vai gerar um *result set* temporário e aplicar o `WHERE` em seguida, o que não é muito performático. Mas, como no seu caso se trata de `LIKE` com `%` dos dois lados, acaba dando na mesma, pois de qualquer forma serão lidos os registros um a um (em todos os casos).

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 'web_tv' AS tabela, campo1, campo2 FROM web_tv
    UNION
    SELECT 'agenda' AS tabela, campo1, campo2 FROM agenda
    UNION
    SELECT 'blog'   AS tabela, campo1, campo2 FROM blog
    UNION
    SELECT 'osorio' AS tabela, campo1, campo2 FROM osorio
) todos
WHERE todos.campo1 LIKE '%".$busca."%' OR todos.campo2 ....
ORDER BY todos.campo1
```