# PHP | MYSQL Erro: Operand should contain 10 column(s)

Tags: php, mysql, select, sql-select

Estou tentando desenvolver uma Query onde, precisa ser Consultado em 6 tabelas iguais se há algum valor específico.

Aqui está a minha Query:

```
SELECT (
    CASE WHEN (SELECT * FROM sala1 WHERE aluno = '$AlunoInformado') = 1 THEN END 
    ELSE
        CASE WHEN(SELECT * FROM sala2 WHERE aluno = '$AlunoInformado') = 1 THEN END
        ELSE
            CASE WHEN(SELECT * FROM sala3 WHERE aluno = '$AlunoInformado') = 1 THEN END
            ELSE
                CASE WHEN(SELECT * FROM sala4 WHERE aluno = '$AlunoInformado') = 1 THEN END
                ELSE
                    CASE WHEN(SELECT * FROM sala5 WHERE aluno = '$AlunoInformado') = 1 THEN END
                    ELSE
                        CASE WHEN(SELECT * FROM sala6 WHERE aluno = '$AlunoInformado') = 1 THEN END
                        END
                    END
                END
            END
        END
    END
)entrada FROM $SelectSalas WHERE status = 0
```

OBS: `$AlunoInformado` recebe um valor que pode ter em todas as tabelas.
Mas quando faz a consulta, apresenta Operand should contain 10 column(s).
O que está errado com a query? Porque não apresenta a coluna informada `entrada` conforme a instrução antes do `FROM` ?

Comment: Não é melhor um simples UNION? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/163399/como-buscar-um-mesmo-termo-em-4-tabelas-diferentes - e não seria o caso das tabelas estarem organizadas de forma a ter uma relação aluno-sala em vez de várias tabelas de sala?

Comment: @Bacco Não para este caso, pois preciso separar por salas e por dia de agendamento. Como não sou muito bom em SQL, essa foi a maneira mais simples e rápida que funcionou. O UNION não está retornando resultados, não sei bem o motivo, mas não retorna.

Comment: Se postar uma pequena coleção de dados de exemplo no http://SQLFiddle.com , posso tentar ajudar. Sem os dados e estrutura da tabela, fica mais complicado. Quanto a separar as salas, se você tiver uma coluna "sala" com o numero, basta usar um WHERE para escolher a sala desejada.

Comment: Tem como você postar a estrutura das tabelas que você está usando? Apenas a Estrutura, não precisa especificar os dados, mas as vezes em que esse erro retornou para mim, era porque a tabela que eu estava usando  no FROM tinha menos ou mais colunas do que a quantidade retornada nos SELECT da função

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CASE WHEN (SELECT * FROM sala1 WHERE aluno = '$AlunoInformado') = 1 THEN END 
    ELSE
```

Acredito que o seu CASE WHEN esteja errado, porque vc está colocando o END (o comando que encerra o CASE) antes do seu ELSE.

E até onde eu conheço, você precisa ter um resultado para o seu "WHEN" ou seja, quando o que estiver depois do WHEN for verdadeiro, faça x coisa, se não (que seria o ELSE) faça y coisa.

Pensando da maneira que eu falei, o código ficaria tipo:

```
SELECT (
   CASE 
      WHEN (SELECT * FROM sala1 WHERE aluno = '$AlunoInformado') = 1 THEN 'sala1'
      ELSE
         CASE 
            WHEN(SELECT * FROM sala2 WHERE aluno = '$AlunoInformado') = 1 THEN 'Sala2'
            ELSE 'Não foi encontrado'
         END
   END
) AS entrada 
FROM $SelectSalas 
WHERE status = 0
```

E eu indicaria você colocar algo mais "concreto" no seu WHEN, pois ali você está selecionando todas as colunas de inúmeras tabelas, selecione algo x de cada tabela. Por exemplo o id da mesma, pois assim fica mais fácil de validar a sua condição. Tipo:

```
SELECT
   CASE
      WHEN (SELECT tabela_id FROM tabela_x WHERE cod_aluno = '$código') > 1 THEN 'Exite'
      ELSE 'Não existe'
   END
```

Espero ter ajudado :D

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms181765.aspx

Comment: Não resolveu o problema, mas me deu uma direção para resolver, muito obrigado @jonathan-machado